# Interrupt Eclipse Paho MQTT publish method (Google Cloud) safely?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, paho

I am sending an attach message to Google Cloud IoT Core with QoS 1 (as required by Google docs). However, I am finding that if the device has not been bound to the gateway, then the program times out until the client disconnects from the broker.

The eclipse paho client.publish method is blocking, so the program will never continue and the attach logic is done when the program starts.

I have tried using future/executor service to set a timeout on the client.publish method but paho throws an interrupted exception and re-sends the message. How can I set a timeout on this method in the correct way (so I can receive the error and the program can continue)?

Thanks.

Comment: Add some code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think u need to send QoS 0, so that it doesnt try again and you'll get the error on timeout